# Wrap cordova-http plugin promise as observable

Tags: angular, http, promise, ionic2, observable

We have an application which is currently using angular http client, however angular http client is unable to perform certificate pinning, therefore we need to replace it with ionic-native plugin. This plugin "cordova-HTTP" returns Promise rather then Observable. As this is our core HTTP "router" class, many other services rely on it. Therefore rather then rewriting all those services which expect Observable, I would like to wrap the Prmise as Observable. This is what I attempted to do so far, I am getting no errors on device, but client keeps hanging, like it is waiting for Promise to be resolved. Is my approach and implementation incorrect in anyway?

```
return Observable.fromPromise(this.http.get(url, {}, this.headers,
  (res) => {
    return Promise.resolve(res);
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
      this.login().then( () => {
        return this.http.get(url, {}, this.headers);
      });
    } else {
      this.log.error("Problem with authenticated get", error.error);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
));
```

Comment: Error handling is wrong. No promise is returned from `if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) { ...`, this will obviously make a promise pending. You need the promises to be properly chained. I'm not sure if there are other problems that are are specific to Cordova.

Answer (score 2):

At the end I solved my problem:

```
return Observable.create( (observer) => {
  this.http.get(url, {}, this.headers)
  .then( (response) => {
    observer.next(new AuthResponse(response.headers, response.data));
    observer.complete();
  })
  .catch( (error) => {
    if (error.status === 401 || error.status === 403) {
      this.login().then( () => {
        this.http.get(url, {}, this.headers)
        .then( (response) => {
          observer.next(new AuthResponse(response.headers, response.data));
          observer.complete();
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
          this.log.error("Problem with authenticated get", error.error);
          observer.error(error);
        });
      });
    } else {
      this.log.error("Problem with authenticated get", error.error);
      observer.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```